# How to send Facebook gifts without FBML?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

There are similar posts here in SO that sort-of answers this question, but they all use FBML which is being deprecated.

How can I, using non-deprecated methods, send gifts to a list of friends?

I've looked that the [FB Dialogs API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)  but nothing sticks out as giving me the ability to send gifts.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize requests as gifts: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: how would i indicate what gift to send in that api?  can you give some sample code? In Cityville you can send a permit.  How is that done? how does the call look like?